# Trying to float three vertical boxes to the right of one large box

Tags: html, css

I am working on some html / css that I am trying to get to lay out correctly, but I cant understand why it wont work.

I want to have one large main area and three vertically stacked smaller areas to the right of that - but on a narrower page, the three boxes then wrap underneath the main area.

I have the following code, which I think should work, but it only lets one of the smaller boxes show at the side - the other two stay underneath the main box, and I dont understand why!

My code is just test code to try and get this working, and is as follows:

```
<div style="width:650px; height:900px; margin:25px; display:inline-block; background:yellow;"></div>

<div style="width:250px; height:250px; margin:25px; display:inline-block; background:blue;"></div>

<div style="width:250px; height:250px; margin:25px; display:inline-block; background:blue;"></div>

<div style="width:250px; height:250px; margin:25px; display:inline-block; background:blue;"></div>
```

All css is inline, just as a simple test.

This give the following layouts, depending on the browser width.

On a wide window, where I expect three boxes to stack to the right...

[image]

And on narrower window...

[image]

This is what I would expect. It is just the first layout, when the window is wide enough for the divs to show side by side, that I would expect the three blue boxes to stack vertically.

Can anyone see why this doesnt work as I expect?

Comment: You'd need to wrap the three blue divs in their own container to do that.

Comment: Basically, that the way the line-box-model works. When wrapping/overflow occurs, the elements move to the next line **below** the current "row"

Comment: @Paulie_D I think this is probably the right answer. Can you make an answer and provide some code. I cant accept a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `float` property might be cumbersome to use to force the alignment you're looking for. I re-did your code using `display: flex` and other flex-specific properties. Check out a [working pen](https://codepen.io/gtrabbit/pen/EwxPjZ).

Basically, you will need to wrap the three small `div`s in another `div`. Apply `display: flex` to the wrapper `div`, and to outer div holding everything (in my Pen, I just did the whole body). Then, to get everything aligned, you can use `justify-content: center` on both the outer `div` (e.g. the body) and the inner `div` holding the three blue squares.

If you're not familiar with flexbox, MDN has [a good tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Comment: See my comment on other answers. Adding a float doesnt allow the main box to be centred after the blue boxes wrap to underneath it.

Comment: I would suggest using flexbox for that. Check out my revised pen. https://codepen.io/gtrabbit/pen/EwxPjZ